# How to add items to __slots__ when the classes are created with user metaclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, metaprogramming

### The Context

I want to make a tool to create *objects* that don't have the same *attributes*. Finally I decided create a *UniqueInstances* `metaclass`

```
class UniqueInstances(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        dict['instancesAttrs'] = set()

        return super(UniqueInstaces, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)

    def __call__(cls, *args):
        if args not in cls.instancesAttrs:
            cls.instancesAttrs.add(args)

            return super().__call__(*args)
        else:
            print("Warning: " +
                  "There is another instance of the class " +
                  "'{}' ".format(cls.__name__) +
                  "with the same attributes. The object was not created.")

            return None
```

With this `metaclass` I can create *classes* that avoid create objects with the same attributes

```
class Coordinate(metaclass=UniqueInstances):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


myObj = Coordinate(0, 0, 0)
myObj = Coordinate(0, 0, 0)  # Warning: There is another instance...
```

and its works.

### The Problem

I want classes created with this tool have a `__slots__` to optimize the instances. I can add to the `dict` the `__slot__` key with an empty tuple

```
class UniqueInstances(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict):
        dict['instancesAttrs'] = set()
        dict['__slots__'] = ()

        return super(UniqueInstaces, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)
```

and its works

```
class MyClass(metaclass=UniqueInstances):
    pass


myObj = MyClass()
print(myObj.__dict__)  # AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

But, I don't know how to add items to `__slots__`

```
class Coordinate(metaclass=UniqueInstances):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y', 'z')

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z


myObj = Coordinate(0, 0, 0)  # AttributeError: 'Coordinate' object has no attribute 'x'
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little ugly, but you can pass keyword arguments to the metaclass in the class definition syntax, so something like:

```
class Coordinate(metaclass=UniqueInstances, slots=('x', 'y', 'z')):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

And the metaclass can handle it as follows:

```
class UniqueInstances(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict, **kwargs):
        dict['instancesAttrs'] = set()
        slots = kwargs.get('slots')
        if slots is not None:
            dict['__slots__'] = slots

        return super(UniqueInstances, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)
```

### EDIT:

Actually, I just checked and just using `__slots__` works, you can just remove `dict['__slots__'] = ()` in the metaclass, so just:

```
class UniqueInstances(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dict, **kwargs):
        dict['instancesAttrs'] = set()
        return super(UniqueInstances, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, dict)

class Coordinate(metaclass=UniqueInstances):
    __slots__ = ('x','y','z')
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
```

Works. It creates the slotted class you'd expect.

Comment: Its works. But yeah, it's a little ugly. Wait for a better implementation. Thank you !

Comment: @rvcristiand actually, the fix is much simpler... see my edit